# jQuery UI map - panTo user location

Tags: google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-map

Long time reader/ first time poster here, with a question I suspect will be easy to answer but help me out no end.

I simply want to i) retrieve the user's location, ii) display an icon at this location, and iii) Have a button labelled 'Find Me' that pans the map to this location.

I have i) and ii) working, but although I have other buttons that pan to a particular location, this one doesn't seem to work:

```
        var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
        var mapHeight = viewportHeight - 93;
        var map;
        var union = new google.maps.LatLng(53.806828, -1.555999);
        var userLocation;
        var userIcon = 'userIcon.png';
        var parkinson = new google.maps.LatLng(53.808, -1.553);
        var unionDescription = '<div id="content">' + '<div id="siteNotice">' + '</div>' + '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Your Union</h2>' + '<div id="bodyContent">' + '<p>Heres a bit about us</p>' + '</div>' + '</div>';


        //Try and get the user's location

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var userLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
                    'position': userLocation,
                    'bounds': false,
                    'icon': userIcon
                });
            });
        };



        //initialise the map
        $(function () {


            $('#map_canvas').gmap({
                'center': union,
                'zoom': 16,
                'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                'styles': campusStyles,
                'minZoom': 15,
                'maxZoom': 17
            }).bind('init', function (ev, map) {

                $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
                    'position': parkinson,
                    'bounds': false
                }).click(function () {
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
                        'content': 'Hello World!'
                    }, this);
                });

                $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
                    'position': union,
                    'bounds': true
                }).click(function () {
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
                        'content': unionDescription
                    }, this);
                });

                $('#map_canvas').height(mapHeight);
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                $('#unionButton').click(function () {
                    map.panTo(union);
                });
                $('#findMe').click(function () {
                    map.panTo(userLocation);
                });

                $('#map_canvas').height(mapHeight);
            });

        });
```

Thing I'm actually working on here: http://jdp.org.uk/tests/mapstest4.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but my navigator geolocation is not working, so I just bypassed that requirement and hard-coded a user LatLng. What worked for me was cutting and pasting the whole  block `if(navigator.geolocaton)` to directly below the block with the line `$('#unionButton').click(function(){map.panTo(union);});`. It appears that `map` was not yet defined where you had the geolocation code.

From my testing, smooth panning only happens when the current position is close to the target. http://jsfiddle.net/EejRt/

I have:

```
    $('#map_canvas').height(mapHeight);
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    $('#unionButton').click(function(){map.panTo(union);}); 
    $('#map_canvas').height(mapHeight);

//if (navigator.geolocation) { 
//  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {  
//    var userLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
    var userLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(53.8018,-1.553);
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': userLocation, 'bounds': false,  'icon' : userIcon });
    $('#findMe').click(function(){map.panTo(userLocation)});
//  });
//  };
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help :)

If I define a LatLng value manually it does work just fine, but it won't work when it tries to pick up the geolocation.

It's strange because userLocation definitely gets defined properly (because addMarker users it and it works), but when I try and use userLocation to panTo, nothing happens.

Comment: sorry, hit enter before I'd finished my reply

Comment: Sorry to cut you off. I'll try to get my browser to geolocate and try some other things

Comment: OK, try it now https://files.nyu.edu/hc742/public/googlemaps/stackme3.html The problem was geocoding does not work on my local machine (opening from disk)

Comment: Thank you very much! I see now the reason it wasn't working is I was including the click handler outside of the gmap function.

Comment: You're welcome! I learned about geolocation so we both benefited.